# What should be my Android package name?

Tags: java, android, naming-conventions

I am new to Android development, and i don't know what should be my Android package name. My developer name is: "G.Games" and i don't have an own domain. Can i use this: com.g.games.appname ?

Comment: Sure, you can use anything you want. Having a domain is not mandatory.

Comment: If you don't have a domain, you could even remove the `com.` leaving `g.games.appname`

Comment: If you are not going to base your package name on a domain you control or have permission to use this way, it would be better to avoid making it look like domain based naming. That way, if anyone gets "g.com" as a domain name in the future you will not be in conflict.

Comment: "i don't have an own domain" -- either the app is for internal use within some organization, or it is designed for public use. For internal use, the organization probably has a domain name. For public use, you need a domain name for your Web site, as part of the overall marketing plan for your app, which you need **before** writing the app. If you are not going to market your app, then do not expect anyone to find the app, let alone use the app.

Comment: Thanks! If it's good, then i will use the g.games.appname!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a package name begins with the top level domain name of the organization and then the organization's domain and then any subdomains, listed in reverse order. The organization can then choose a specific name for its package. Subsequent components of the package name vary according to an organization's own internal naming conventions.

For example, if an organization in Canada called MySoft creates a package to deal with fractions, naming the package ca.mysoft.fractions distinguishes the fractions package from another similar package created by another company.

for instance, packages from Adobe would be of the form:

> com.adobe.reader (Adobe Reader)
>
> com.adobe.photoshop (Adobe Photoshop)
>
> com.adobe.ideas (Adobe Ideas)

The concept comes from Package Naming Conventions in Java, more about which can be read here:

[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package#Package_naming_conventions)

[quora](http://www.quora.com/Why-do-a-majority-of-Android-package-names-begin-with-com)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers. Links can die and they add clutter rather than information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any name you want as long as it wont conflict with any other package name in the play store. There are huge number of applications in the store so if you use your own name chances are there may be some application with the same name. By using a domain name you can be sure that there are no other packages of the same name. For more details you can refer this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html
Look under the package paragraph. Hope this helps you.

Comment: The general convention is that you use the reverse of a domain that you own and control. It is the only real way to avoid duplicates.